# Show Filtered Stock Item in a certain Branch

Tags: acumatica, erp

how to show a filtered non-stock/stock items in a certain Branch in #acumatica?

Have tried to limit it with following action, but still didn't work

1. the branches in Users Management,
2. Manage Restriction Group in Items.

need advice on how to add a filtered non-stock/stock items in a certain transactional Branch (Request, PO)

Comment: Welcome! can you share a screen or scenario in Acumatica where you have seen this? you need to elaborate the question more. Not enough details. Share your current implementation and the issues you have faced

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to force purchase orders only for the items in that users branch, I would use the Create Purchase Orders screen (PO505000)

Make a graph extension that will default the WarehouseID to the default warehouse that is in their profile

Then you would lock down the field with user security for users who need it locked. I would also lock down the default warehouse on the user profile, or else the employees could change it themselves and access another branch.

The same could be done for the Prepare Replenishment screen (IN508000)